# Regarding interface declaration which was parallel

Tags: java, interface, constants, declaration

I was going through code walk through in which I have discovered that an interface was used for constants declaration but the thing that I have found that in interface are like below..

```
public interface abcConstants extends Serializable
 {

int def = 4;
int efg = 7;

}
```

Please let me know that it is correct as per my knowledge constants should have publis static final too..!!

Comment: [Constant interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface) is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All declared variables in interfaces are `public static final`.

Methods in interfaces are `public abstract`.

Adding the above keywords in front of the variables or methods in interfaces is redundant, but may help reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

[JLS#9.3. Field (Constant) Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is **implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.**

How ever you should Avoid using `interface for constant declaration and Define enum instead`.

Answer (score 0):

variables declared inside an interface are by default **public static final**. you dont need to **explicitly** mark them such. and also all the **methods declared in the interface** are marked **public abstract** by default 
so, ..

```
public interface abcConstants extends Serializable
{

int def = 4;
int efg = 7;

}
```

is equivalent to

```
public interface abcConstants extends Serializable
{

public static final int def = 4;
public static final int efg = 7;

}
```